Xamarin Forms, how to call the respective view model based on different menu?
I have 2 functions which going to call the same UI. In my menu, I passed in the menu name as one of the parameter. Can I based on the different menu name pass in from the navigation bar, call different ViewModel to display the respective data?
sample code below:
StartPage.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="StartPage"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
    Title="{Binding Title}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <converters:IsEmptyCollectionConverter x:Key="IsEmptyCollectionConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <prism:ViewModelLocator:
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid RowDefinitions="*,Auto" RowSpacing="0">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0">
                    <Label Text="{Binding text}"
                               Style="{StaticResource InputTitleLabelStyle}"
                               Padding="{StaticResource BaseInputPadding}"/>
                    <ListView
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Datas}"
                    RowHeight="{StaticResource DoubleRowListItemHeight}"
                    ItemSelected="OnItemSelected">

                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout
                                        Padding="{StaticResource ListWithChevronPadding}"
                                        Orientation="Horizontal"
                                        Spacing="6">

                                        <StackLayout
                                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                            Orientation="Vertical"
                                            Spacing="0"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center">
                                            <!--  RETURN NO LABEL  -->
                                            <Label Style="{StaticResource AppLabelStyle}" Text="{Binding DocNo}" />

                                            <!--  STORE LABEL  -->
                                            <Label Style="{StaticResource AppSubLabelStyle}" Text="{Binding ShipFromCode}" />

                                            <!--  DELIVERY DATE LABEL  -->
                                            <Label Style="{StaticResource AppSubLabelStyle}" Text="{Binding ProposedScheduleString}" />
                                        </StackLayout>

                                        <!--  STATUS LABEL  -->
                                        <Label
                                            HorizontalOptions="End"
                                            Style="{StaticResource AppLabelStyle}"
                                            Text="{Binding Status}"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center" />

                                        <controls:ChevronView HorizontalOptions="End" />
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>

                    </ListView>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>

            <Label
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                IsVisible="{Binding Datas, Converter={StaticResource IsEmptyCollectionConverter}}"
                Style="{StaticResource AppLabelStyle}"
                Text="{helpers:Translate Common_NoDataLabel}"
                VerticalOptions="Center" />

                <Button
                     Margin="{StaticResource BaseMargin}"
                     Command="{Binding NewReturnCommand}"
                     Style="{StaticResource PrimaryActionButtonStyle}"
                     Text="{helpers:Translate RTWStoreReturnStartPage_NewReturnButton}"
                     VerticalOptions="End" />

                <controls:LoadingView IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}"/>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>

StartPage.xaml.cs
public partial class StartPage : ContentPage
{
    public StartPageViewModel ViewModel { get { return BindingContext as StartPageViewModel; } }
    public StartPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem is StoreReturnMasterDto item)
        {
            await ViewModel.HandleOnItemSelected(item);
        }

        ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
    }
}

StartPageViewModel.cs
 public class StartPageViewModel : BasePageViewModel
 {
  public override async void OnNavigatedTo(INavigationParameters parameters)
  {
    base.OnNavigatedTo(parameters);

    if (parameters.ContainsKey("MenuName"))
    {
        menuName = parameters.GetValue<string>("MenuName");

        switch (menuName)
        {
            case "StoreReturn":
                Title = Strings.MenuPage_StoreReturn;
                break;
        }
    }
  }
}

